# Python urllib2 returning an empty string

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to retrieve the following URL: http://www.winkworth.co.uk/sale/property/flat-for-sale-in-masefield-court-london-n5/HIH140004.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.winkworth.co.uk/rent/property/terraced-house-to-rent-in-mill-road--/WOT140129')
response.read()
```

However I'm getting an empty string. When I try it through the browser or with cURL it works fine. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Is `urlopen` asynchronous?  If so, maybe it isn't finished downloading when you try to read it?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: nope, `urlopen` is synchronous. It is the server being broken by not returning anything when no `Accept` header is present.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got a response when using the `requests` library but not when using `urllib2`, so I experimented with HTTP request headers.

As it turns out, the server expects an `Accept` header; `urllib2` doesn't send one, `requests` and cURL send `*/*`.

Send one with `urllib2` as well:

```
url = 'http://www.winkworth.co.uk/sale/property/flat-for-sale-in-masefield-court-london-n5/HIH140004'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://www.winkworth.co.uk/sale/property/flat-for-sale-in-masefield-court-london-n5/HIH140004'
>>> len(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
0
>>> request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})
>>> len(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
37197
```

The server is at fault here; [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1) states:

> If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the
> client accepts all media types.